# What is the Lagrangian for FRW universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

A straightforward calculation to the Lagrangian for FRW as $\mathscr{L}=\sqrt{-g}R$ gets me the following result:

$$\mathscr{L}\sim a^3\big(\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}+(\frac{\dot{a}}{a})^2+\frac{k}{a^2} \big)$$

However, in the context of the Hamiltonian formulation, I notice authors citing the Lagrangian for FRW as

$$\mathscr{L}\sim a^3\big((\frac{\dot{a}}{a})^2+\frac{k}{a^2} \big)$$

Why are they dropping the $\ddot{a}$ term? or is there a certain gauge for which this term is irrelevant?

Comment: Which authors ?

Comment: i.e. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08531) equation 2.2

Comment: Hint: The term $a^3\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}$ is equal to $-2a^3(\frac{\dot{a}}{a})^2$ modulo a total time derivative.

Comment: I see, $a^3\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}=-2a^3\big(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\big)^2+\frac{d}{dt}(a^2\dot{a})$ and the total derivative is disregarded as a surface term.